# React Native Touchable Highlight not changing style of Child 'View' and 'Text'

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm developing an App in React Native, I'm stuck on one thing.

There is a **TouchableHighlight** with a child View and Text, my requirement is when a user touches that **TouchableHighlight** then styling of Child "View" and "Text" should be changed. But It is not working, It only shows changing of **underlayColor** nothing else.

Following is My code:

Here I'm trying to achieve this thing by changing the state on Calling of "onHideUnderlay" and "onShowUnderlay" and according to that state's value, I change the styling of View and Text.

**One Important thing**: It is working perfectly when I try it on react-native emulator https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight but it is not working in Local Emulator android or IOS.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { ThanksModalCheck: false, ButtonPressed:false }
  }
   onHideUnderlay=()=> {
    this.setState({ ButtonPressed: false });
  }
  onShowUnderlay= ()=> {
    this.setState({ ButtonPressed: true });
  }

  onPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count+1
    })
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight 
              activeOpacity={1}
              style={this.state.ButtonPressed ? styles.ListViewBadgeContainerStyle_2 : styles.ListViewBadgeContainerStyle}
              onPress={() => {this.setState({ ThanksModalCheck: true })}}
              underlayColor="#ffffff"
              onShowUnderlay={()=> this.onShowUnderlay()}
              onHideUnderlay={()=> this.onHideUnderlay()}
              >
              <View>
                <Text style={(this.state.ButtonPressed) ? styles.badgeTextStyle_2 : styles.badgeTextStyle}>Suggest</Text>
              </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },
  ListViewBadgeContainerStyle: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    backgroundColor: '#161fd1',
    width:150, height: 36,
    shadowColor: "rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.29)",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 8
    }, shadowRadius: 10, shadowOpacity: 1, borderRadius:18
  },
  ListViewBadgeContainerStyle_2: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#161fd1',
    width:150, height: 36,
    shadowColor: "rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.29)",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 8
    }, shadowRadius: 10, shadowOpacity: 1, borderRadius:18
  },
  badgeTextStyle: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: "normal",
    fontStyle: "normal",
    letterSpacing: 0,
    textAlign: "center",
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: "#ffffff"
  },
  badgeTextStyle_2: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: "normal",
    fontStyle: "normal",
    letterSpacing: 0,
    textAlign: "center",
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: "#161fd1"
  },
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)
```

**I'm also attaching my packge.json file because I think this issue may be relevant to react-native version.**

**packge.json**

```
{
  "name": "reactApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.7.0",
    "json-server": "^0.14.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-atoz-listview": "0.0.7",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-fcm": "^16.2.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-icon-checkbox": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.21.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.10",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.4.0",
    "react-native-material-bottom-navigation": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "0.0.29",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-range-slider": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.7",
    "react-native-search-bar": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-search-box": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-slideshow": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-sortable-grid": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-svg-image": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-view-overflow": "0.0.3",
    "react-navigation": "^2.12.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "relative-date": "^1.1.3",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, it worked on my simulator. Does it also have the same problem on a real device?

Comment: yes, it is also not working on  real devices Android | IOS both,